# Jquery check if div contains children with 2 id's and no more

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am designing a drag & drop question.

The answer to the question will have two or more answers.. (for this exercise only two)

I can get the script to identify if one of the elements is inside the div but I only want a positive result if both elements are inside the div.

Also if any incorrect answer is inside the div it will not return a possitive result.

For this exercise box 1 & 2 are the correct answers.
Box 3 is incorrect.

```
$('.checkanswer').on('click', function(event) {
if ($(".targetbox").find(".ans1, .ans2").length > 0){ 
document.getElementById('showme').style.display = "block";
}
else {
alert("Hello! Boxes 1 & 2  are not in the correct place.");
}
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle with the question:
[DEMO LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/worldscrown/yfbt0en4/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 //question results
 $('.checkanswer').on('click', function (event) {
     if (    $(".targetbox .ans1").length > 0 
          && $(".targetbox .ans2").length > 0
          && $(".targetbox").children().length == 2) {
           document.getElementById('showme').style.display = "block";
       } 
       else {
         alert("Hello! Boxes 1 & 2  are not in the correct place.");
       }
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sfxpdevq/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition in the correctness test exploiting that only the dragged answers in the target box are its children:

```
$('.checkanswer').on('click', function(event) {
    if (
           $(".ans1").parent().hasClass("targetbox")
        && $(".ans2").parent().hasClass("targetbox")
        && !$(".ans3").parent().hasClass("targetbox")
    ) {
        document.getElementById('showme').style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        alert("Hello! Boxes 1 & 2  are not in the correct place.");
    }
});
```

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4a4jsu79/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do this would be to separate out the `find()` calls in your check, like this (below).

```
    //question results
    $('.checkanswer').on('click', function(event) {
    if ($(".targetbox").find(".ans1").length > 0 
       && $(".targetbox").find(".ans2").length > 0 
       && $(".targetbox").find(".ans3").length === 0){ 
       document.getElementById('showme').style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
       alert("Hello! Boxes 1 & 2  are not in the correct place.");
    }
    });
```